# WPF String Format Question

Tags: wpf, string

I have an input of a random string of twelve characters like this:

ABABABABABAB

I want them to display like this:

ABAB-ABAB-ABAB

How do I format a string in this way.  I'm trying to use StringFormat, but it seems like the wrong approach.

```
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Key" Mode="OneWay" StringFormat="???" />
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct format string that you could use to achieve the formatting you are looking for but you can implement your own [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and use it to format your string. Here's [an example](http://www.akhildeshpande.com/2011/01/ivalueconverter-example.html) (it's for WP7 but the concept it the same).